# How to get a value from a stdClass object?

Tags: php, object

I use `print_r($arr)`, which prints out the following:

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [uid] => 1 
  [status] => complete 
  [order_id] => 430 
)
```

How do I access those values?

I have tried:

```
print $arr->order_id;
```

but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please, can we have the piece of code that builds it too?

Comment: Unless $arr isn't the right variable, that syntax is correct. Something else is going on

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://3v4l.org/XBkZD).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = array ( 
   "uid" => 1,
   "status" => "complete",
   "order_id" => 430,
);

$a = (object)$a;

echo $a->order_id;
// 430
```

This works fine.